# How to add captcha to "Printer, e-mail and PDF versions" email form

Tags: 6, captcha

I am using the Printer, e-mail and PDF versions module to enable user to share pages on my d6 website. 
Now I  have recently noticed that some robots make thousands of requests on this form a nd I need a captcha to prevent it. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added my send form ID to the CAPTCHA form list, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The correct ID for that is **print_mail_form**. The HTML has:

```
 id="print-mail-form"
```

but you must change - to _ to get the internal ID.