# How to add captcha to pdf version

Tags: captcha

I want to add a captcha to the PDF generator from the [Print Module](http://drupal.org/project/print) so that my server doesn't waste time generating a PDF for robots and to prevent DOS attacks.

There is a [similar question asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12674/how-to-add-captcha-to-printer-e-mail-and-pdf-versions-email-form), but the accepted answer doesn't actually answer my question (the PDF Version part), but rather only the E-mail part.

Since the PDF Version doesn't link to a form, there isn't a form ID I can add to the Captcha module. Is there a way to require a CaPTCHA to download/generate a PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should avoid captcha, their are not user friendly. But good new, in this case you don't need it :).

Print module generate the pdf once and cache it https://drupal.org/node/516466#comment-6390678. So DOS are not possible on pdf generation.

You can still have DOS by requesting a pdf thousand of time, saturating your bandwidth. If you are really worried about that you can for example configure Apache with mod_evasive http://systembash.com/content/how-to-stop-an-apache-ddos-attack-with-mod_evasive/

By robot I suppose you mean search engine robot. You can add that in your robot.txt (But I think is not necessary):

```
User Agent: *
Disallow: /*.pdf$
```